# How to write query in active record to select from two or more tables in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I don't want to use join

I want to  manually compare any field with other table field

for example

SELECT u.user_id, t.task_id

FROM  tasks t, users u

WHERE u.user_id = t.user_id

how can i write this query in Rails ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have associations in your models, you can simply do as follow

```
User.joins(:tasks).select('users.user_id, tasks.task_id')
```

you can also do as follow

```
User.includes(:tasks).where("user.id =tasks.user_id")
```

includes will do eager loading check the example below or read eager loading at [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html)

```
users = User.limit(10)

users.each do |user|
  puts user.address.postcode
end
```

This will run 11 queries, it is called N+1 query problem(first you query to get all the rows then you query on each row again to do something). with includes Active Record ensures that all of the specified associations are loaded using the minimum possible number of queries.

Now when you do;

```
users = User.includes(:address).limit(10)

user.each do |user|
  puts user.address.postcode
end
```

It will generate just 2 queries as follow

```
SELECT * FROM users LIMIT 10
SELECT addresses.* FROM addresses
  WHERE (addresses.user_id IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10))
```

Plus if you don't have associations then read below;

you should be have to look at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html
Assuming your are trying to do inner join, by default in rails when we associate two models and then query on them then we are doing inner join on those tables.

You have to create associations between the models example is given below

```
class User
  has_many :reservations
  ...# your code
end
```

And in reservations

```
class Reservations
  belongs_to :user
  ... #your code
end
```

Now when you do

```
User.joins(:reservations)
```

the generated query would look like as follow

```
"SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` INNER JOIN `reservations` ON `reservations`.`user_id` = `users`.`id`"
```

you can check the query by doing `User.joins(:reservations).to_sql` in terminal

Hopefully it would answer your question

Comment: I want to select from two tables... comparing in where clause

Answer (score 1):

```
User.find_by_sql("YOUR SQL QUERY HERE")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use as follows..

```
 User.includes(:tasks).where("user.id =tasks.user_id").order(:user.id)
```